Dagger2 injection across modules replace implementation of Interface
I am breaking up my project into different Android Studio modules.  At the base, I have a headless modules with core business logic. Down the module dependency tree, I have an app modules that encompasses the Android Application.
In the core logic, I am using dependency injection for things like logging/error handling.  In my core module, there is a good amount of code that leverages the interface I am trying to log to, so I am using an EntryPoint to provide the Logging class.
In the app module, I have the "real" logging code that will handle sending info to the server.  So I really want to "inject" THAT implementation when I build the entire project so that all the code gets the real one.
I have searched and read a number of articles on Dagger2, modules, binding, and componenents but I have not found a way to allow the the core module to compile my core module (outside of using Optional) while using my real implementation in the application.
In a perfect world, I can see two solutions:

Try to ignore the dependency injection in the core module knowing it will be provided in the app module.  I saw a library prop in Dagger 1 that appeared to do this.
Provide a dummy implementation of the interface in the core module and then swap it out in the app module for the real implementation when I build the apk.  I think this MIGHT be possible with subcomponents but haven't had luck...

Any help would be really appreciated!

How is this structured in Dagger? Does your core component have its own Dagger Component, and your Android app uses Hilt? Or does your core app offer a Module only and you would like it to play well with Hilt but be testable in isolation?

@JeffBowman that is a good question.  The Android app uses Hilt (annotated with @HiltAndroidApp).  The core module does define an @EntryPoint and a @Module to provide and access the Logger.
I believe they are all under one "Dagger Component".
The goal is to get the core (gradle) module to compile as it is not used by itself, and to have the app (gradle) module inject the real implementation.
I believe testing is working or I can hopefully use Mocking to resolve any issues with testing, so that is not a concern at this point

Even though you don't seem to be using Android feature modules, it sounds like your module dependencies might still match the Hilt multi-module page. Otherwise, as that page describes, you can just use the main Dependency Injection with Hilt codelab as a model.
It sounds like your core module doesn't have a @Component defined at all, so there should be no problem compiling with missing bindings—perhaps that's what you mean by your option 1, "try to ignore the dependency injection". Your @EntryPoint and @Module will refer to a Logger without provided bindings, but unless you've triggered Hilt code generation by specifying a @HiltAndroidApp, your core Gradle module should stand alone just fine. (If you're getting a compilation error, please edit your question to include it and I'll edit my answer.)
Naturally, if your app depends on your core, you'll need the Logger interface to move into core (or a common app dependency) to avoid a circular dependency. The server-facing implementation might stay with app, leaving the core less-useful for lack of a working Logger, but based on your question comments it doesn't sound like that's a problem in your app layout.

However, if you do want to possibly compile your core and also generate a DI graph as a Component (with or without Hilt), you might instead favor a binding like @BindsOptionalOf:
// in an abstract @Module or @Module interface
@BindsOptionalOf fun bindOptionalLogger(): Logger;

With this binding (which can appear anywhere and be duplicated if needed), you can inject an Optional<Logger> wherever you'd like; the Logger will be present in Components where a binding exists for it, and will be absent in Components that haven't defined that binding. This entails injecting an Optional<Logger> instead of a pure Logger, though, so if you'd like to hide that machinery you can make the binding slightly more indirect:
@Qualifier
annotation class WithFallback

// in your module
@Provides
@WithFallback
fun bindLoggerWithFallback(
    optionalLogger: Optional<Logger>,
    fallbackLogger: Provider<FallbackLogger>
): Logger = if (optionalLogger.isPresent()) optionalLogger.get() else fallbackLogger.get()

This technique offers a new binding, @WithFallback Logger, using a qualifier annotation. This means that regardless of whether you have a Logger bound in your graph, you will always have an intelligent @WithFallback Logger. That said, you could even invert this pattern to make it as opaque as possible: In your app you could install your Logger as a @ServerSide Logger, have your @Provides method bind Logger itself, and inject a @ServerSide Optional<Logger> to evaluate when choosing whether to invoke your Provider<FallbackLogger>. That way even your core will always have a Logger, whether it's a server-side logger in your core or a presumably-to-stderr FallbackLogger you write.
As a final alternative, if you're allergic to Optional, you can make it a point to annotate your bindings and injection sites with @Nullable and then inject null in a Module that is specific to your core Component graph. You'll need to be careful not to include that module in your app Module graph or you'll risk a duplicate binding, and it will result in proliferation of @Nullable annotations, but you can avoid the extra expense of Optional. Of course, you can use the same techniques above (but checking for null instead of Optional absence) to inject a @WithFallback Logger or inject a pure Logger having bound a @ServerSide Logger. Your choice.
